# Frequently update varying sized parts of vertex buffer

Tags: javascript, webgl, vertex-buffer

I am implementing a rendering of large set of elements in webgl, for efficiency all vertex information of said elements is to be stored in a single vertex buffer.
When some element updates it should update it's vertex information in the vertex buffer (cache). My question is how to efficiently manage the vertex buffer?
If the number of vertices is the same, it's not an issue, but what if the number of generated vertices is smaller or even worse, larger than it used to be?
Any ideas and insights are welcome.
Note that I am using webgl1 and it's possible to update the vertex buffer, but impossible to copy from it, so rearranging data is not the option unless I also have a CPU copy of the data and upload all of it after each change, which seems to be not efficient.

Comment: what makes you think having one vertex buffer will be more efficient?

Comment: 1. Because swapping buffers is expensive, especially when you might have hundreds of thousands of objects 2. Because I actually tested it

Comment: How did you test it? if you are using vertex array objectd I should be a single call to set all buffers and attributes between objects

Comment: I am reluctant to use VAOs as they are not natively available in  webgl1, there is an extension, but the support is currently limited. However, even if I was to use it, I still would need to bind thousands of vertex buffers which is very slow.

Comment: Support is not limited. VAOs work on like 99.9% of all WebGL machines. Those machines that don't support them are the same machines that are going to be too slow for whatever app you're making that you think you need to optimize to the level you're optimizing. If you want your app to still run on those machines [use a polyfill](https://github.com/greggman/oes-vertex-array-object-polyfill).

Comment: Thanks for the insight gman, however, VAOs don't solve the issue of updating the buffers with frequently and differently sized information. They merely manage the client state of the buffers. To be clearer, If I have 100 different objects (lets say polylines) and those polylines are editable in a way where I can either move some of the vertices , add more vertices or remove some, then by your suggestion I need to have a separate vertex buffer for each of them. Then to draw them all I'll have to bind the buffers 100 times per frame. What will happen if there are 100000 of them?

Comment: I am currently leaning towards keeping a copy of the buffer on the CPU and making all the updates there , then copy the changed part over to the GPU buffer (or making a  new one if the size grows beyond the original allocation)